# expand <div> from middle

Tags: javascript, html, css, electron

I have a div that I expand by 10% each time i scroll with the mouse scrollwheel. The problem i that it expands from the to left corner. How can I expand it from the middle instead?

I have searched for a solution, but the answers I found was related with animation.

HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="holder" />
</body>
```

JS

```
zoom = value => {
    let size = value;
    return {
        up: () => {
            size += 10;
            holder.style.height = `${size}%`;
            holder.style.width = `${size}%`;
        },
        down: () => {
            size -= 10;
            holder.style.height = `${size}%`;
            holder.style.width = `${size}%`;
        }
    }
}
zoom = zoom(100);

document.onmousewheel = event => {
    (event.wheelDelta > 0) ? zoom.up() : zoom.down();
}
```

CSS

```
body {
    background-color: rgb(33, 37, 43);
    align-content: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#holder {
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    background: url("some-image.jpg") no-repeat center/contain;
}
```

```js
var zoom = value => {
        let size = value;
        return {
            up: () => {
                size += 10;
       holder.style.height = `${size}%`;
       holder.style.width = `${size}%`;
            },
            down: () => {
                size -= 10;
       holder.style.height = `${size}%`;
       holder.style.width = `${size}%`;
            }
        }
    }
    zoom = zoom(100);
    
    document.onmousewheel = event => {
  (event.wheelDelta > 0) ? zoom.up() : zoom.down();
 }
```

```css
.body {
        background-color: rgb(33, 37, 43);
        align-content: center;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    #holder {
        height:100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin: auto;
        background: url("http://placehold.it/300x300") no-repeat center/contain;
    }
```

```html
<div class="body">
<div id="holder" />
</div>
```

Comment: every time the size go up you have to move the div left proportionally. Similarly when the size goes down move the div right. The div also needs to be positioned absolutely so it can expand in width on both sides.

Comment: @NawedKhan, that is one option.  Another option is using `transform: scale()` and `transform-origin`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `flexbox` is an option, you can just add `display: flex` to the `body` - see demo below:

```js
zoom = value => {
  let size = value;
  return {
    up: () => {
      size += 10;
      holder.style.height = `${size}%`;
      holder.style.width = `${size}%`;
    },
    down: () => {
      size -= 10;
      holder.style.height = `${size}%`;
      holder.style.width = `${size}%`;
    }
  }
}
zoom = zoom(100);

document.onmousewheel = event => {
  (event.wheelDelta > 0) ? zoom.up(): zoom.down();
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(33, 37, 43);
  align-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex; /* ADDED */
  height: 100vh; /* initial height*/
}

#holder {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  background: url("http://placehold.it/100x100") no-repeat center/contain;
}
```

```html
<div id="holder" />
```

Another approach would be *positioning* - see below:

```js
zoom = value => {
  let size = value;
  return {
    up: () => {
      size += 10;
      holder.style.height = `${size}%`;
      holder.style.width = `${size}%`;
    },
    down: () => {
      size -= 10;
      holder.style.height = `${size}%`;
      holder.style.width = `${size}%`;
    }
  }
}
zoom = zoom(100);

document.onmousewheel = event => {
  (event.wheelDelta > 0) ? zoom.up(): zoom.down();
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(33, 37, 43);
  align-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh; /* initial height*/
}

#holder {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  background: url("http://placehold.it/100x100") no-repeat center/contain;
  /* ADDED THESE */
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="holder" />
```

Comment: Why does `display: flex;` work even with an oversized `#holder`?

Answer (score 2):

You're pretty close! I updated your snippet so it's runnable; changed the body selector to a class but that's just for demo purposes.

You just need to declare a few more things in your css to get the benefits of flexbox and its centering abilities.

```js
var zoom = value => {
        let size = value;
        return {
            up: () => {
                size += 10;
       holder.style.height = `${size}%`;
       holder.style.width = `${size}%`;
            },
            down: () => {
                size -= 10;
       holder.style.height = `${size}%`;
       holder.style.width = `${size}%`;
            }
        }
    }
    zoom = zoom(100);
    
    document.onmousewheel = event => {
  (event.wheelDelta > 0) ? zoom.up() : zoom.down();
 }
```

```css
.body {
        background-color: rgb(33, 37, 43);
        align-content: center;
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100vw;

        /* This part! */
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    #holder {
        height:100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin: auto;
        background: url("http://placehold.it/300x300") no-repeat center/contain;
    }
```

```html
<div class="body">
<div id="holder" />
</div>
```